# How to enable Xdebug feature

Tags: php, xdebug

How to enable all features on Xdebug? Xdebug has six features and only one feature is active in my Xdebug. I've read the Xdebug documentation but still don't get it. Thank you.

[image: my active xdebug feature]

Comment: I believe you can put multiple values in there.

Comment: You can read it in your picture, you need to set [`xdebug.mode`](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#xdebug.mode).

Answer (score 3):

From [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug):

> You can enable multiple modes at the same time by comma separating their identifiers as value to xdebug.mode: `xdebug.mode=develop,trace`.

Comment: Although you can, please do remember that each enabled mode adds overhead.

Comment: @Derick That will be next issue for OP :)

Answer (score 0):

***Hi,***

you can enable Xdebug features through properly setting `xdebug.mode` in your PHP configuration file.

---

### Solution

If you want to enable all Xdebug features you should listed all features identifiers separating them with comma as `xdebug.mode` value.
Simply add the following line

```
xdebug.mode=develop,coverage,debug,gcstats,profile,trace
```

in your current *php.ini* file.

---

### Knowledge

You can enable one or more modes through one command or also disable all features. Which feature has which identifier and also all other information you can find in *Xdebug all setting documentation* [here in mode part](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode).

---

Having faced a similar problem myself, I couldn't find a complete answer to it, so after solving the issue, I wrote this answer. I hope that will be helpful also for someone else.

***Cheers***